# ActiveRecord where Float == Float returning empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone please help me understand why searching for Float matches using `where` is not working as below?

```
> latitude = 37.9763

  37.9763

> Branch.first.latitude
  # Branch Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `branches`.* FROM `branches`  ORDER BY `branches`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1

  37.9763

> Branch.first.latitude.class

  Float < Numeric

> latitude.class

  Float < Numeric

> Branch.where(latitude: latitude)
  # Branch Load (11.7ms)  SELECT `branches`.* FROM `branches` WHERE `branches`.`latitude` = 37.9763

  []
```

I also tried `Branch.where("latitude = ?", latitude)` but getting `[]`

**I must be losing my mind.**

```
> Branch.where('latitude = ?', Branch.first.latitude) 
  # Branch Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `branches`.* FROM `branches`  ORDER BY `branches`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  # Branch Load (11.3ms)  SELECT `branches`.* FROM `branches` WHERE (latitude = 37.9763)
  []
```

For anyone curious, I was able to find only 3 cases of `no match` across 2000 branches using the following to find duplicates

```
hash = Branch.group(:business_name, :latitude, :longitude).count
hash.select{|k,v| v > 1}.each do |groupings, count|
  business_name = groupings[0]
  latitude = groupings[1]
  longitude = groupings[2]
  branches = Branch.where(
    business_name: business_name,
    latitude: (latitude - 0.0001)..(latitude + 0.0001),
    longitude: (longitude - 0.0001)..(longitude + 0.0001)
  )
  puts "#{business_name} Count = #{count}"
  puts "#{business_name} Branch Count = #{branches.count}"
  puts "no match" if count != branches.count
end
```

Comment: did you try Branch.where(latitude: latitude.to_f)?

Comment: Yes, I did, but this actually isn't necessary since the class is a match already.

Comment: Please provide raw SQL that ActiveRecord generates for the queries. You can get it from the application log. You can also call `.to_sql` on the relations.

Comment: Ok, I have done that now.

Comment: Thanks. SQL is correct. See @lest's answer then.

Comment: Also, could you tell why you need to search by a coordinate value? Something tells me you want to search for points in some areas instead.

Comment: I am trying to remove duplicate branches and grouping by name and lat/lng

Comment: I think I just figured out a solution.. I was doing a group count first, and selecting only the groups with a count > 0, but now I will do a simple grouping without count for the matching count groups to give me the branches I need to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably happening due to how [floating point numbers are represented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). It's not possible to compare them reliably by using a normal equality comparison. Instead of checking for the exact match it's better to check if the number is in a range or round both numbers to some precision before comparing them.

Regarding the particular example with geographical coordinates (I assume this because `latitude` is used), I would recommend using `decimal` column type instead of `float`.

In case you would like to stick with `float` column, I can suggest checking if the value is in a range, e.g.:

```
Branch.where("latitude > ? AND latitude < ?", latitude - 0.00001, latitude + 0.00001)
```

or

```
Branch.where(latitude: (latitude - 0.00001)..(latitude + 0.00001))
```

Comment: Yes, it will work. I updated the answer with an example that will result in `BETWEEN` being used in the SQL.

Comment: @lest answer is correct but I would also raccomend to switch to `decimal`. using `between` you are just making a workaround for a bigger problem: "You are using the wrong type!". Convert to decimal!